# Not able to Parse a valid javascript Json object with \" to snowflake table using parse_json

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jsonparser

I have the below json object as a json string

```
{
 "type": "employee",
 "details": [
        {
           "key": "name",
           "value": "Kethan \"Ch\""
        }
     ],
  "mobile": "9999999999"
}
```

I'm trying to insert this string to a variant type column in snowflake table using [parse_json](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json) but getting this error

```
Error parsing JSON: missing comma, line 6, pos 30
```

Below is my SQL query I'm running in Snowflake.

```
MERGE INTO PLAY_GROUND.SAMPLE_TABLES.EMPLOYEES AS target
USING (
    SELECT
        '1234'::VARIANT AS EMP_ID,
        '2023-10-19T09:01:42.387Z'::VARIANT AS LAST_MODIFIED,
        PARSE_JSON('{
 "type": "employee",
 "details": [
        {
           "key": "name",
           "value": "Kethan \"Ch\""
        }
     ],
  "mobile": "9999999999"
}')::VARIANT AS DETAILS,
        'india'::VARIANT AS COUNTRY
) AS source
ON target.EMP_ID = source.EMP_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        target.LAST_MODIFIED = source.LAST_MODIFIED,
        target.DETAILS = source.DETAILS,
        target.COUNTRY = source.COUNTRY
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (EMP_ID, LAST_MODIFIED, DETAILS, COUNTRY)
    VALUES (source.EMP_ID, source.LAST_MODIFIED, source.DETAILS, source.COUNTRY);
```

The query is being formed using javascript. I know the reason why it is failing but I'm not sure how to fix this. **"Kethan "Ch""**. How can I store this string in snowflake without replacing the escape characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash `\` itself is an escape token for Snowflake's SQL dialect; as such you'll need to "double escape" backslashes appearing in your JSON:

```
"value": "Kethan \\"Ch\\""
```

Comment: Is there any functionality within snowflake to achieve this ?

Comment: @ck22 The linked duplicate shows exactly how to accomplish that, have you read through that thread?

Comment: That didn't exactly solve my issue. But it gave me a hint on how to solve this.
and this replace expression in javascript did the job for me.
````replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\\\"')````